Browser: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined adding elasticsearch to angular project
Here is my Angular project with an Elasticsearch dependency, repo.
The project functions properly without the Elasticsearch dependency. However, upon adding Elasticsearch logging and updating the files angular.json, webpack.config.ts, and tsconfig.ts as required, the application resolves all dependency issues during the build process but fails to load in the browser.
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at 9172 (log.js":1:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at 9548 (WebSocketClient.js:50:4)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at __webpack_exec__ (external commonjs "zone.js":1:1)
    at external commonjs "zone.js":1:1

Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at 9780 (platform-browser":1:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at 4913 (elastic.service.ts:5:23)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at __webpack_exec__ (log.js":1:1)
    at log.js":1:


From the docs @elastic/elasticsearch is meant for node.js application and I am not sure if it's for frontend applications
Could you check out @elastic/app-search-javascript might help Elasticsearch
Also the error is coming from some invalid configuration in webpack.config.js I commented the full file and the error went away, please configure Webpack for front end applications. require is giving error in frontend context, maybe it's meant for server (you have used a server configuration) I am not well versed with Webpack so I can't help. Maybe raise another question for Webpack implementation.
branch

any other UI framework for elasticsearch?
